# Open new window from managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use this code for open a popup in JavaScript:

```
function showMyPage() { 
 window.open('./showMyPage.xhtml','mywindow', 'resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=450,width=530,top=145,left=235');
 return true;
```

}

But, I want to do it from a Managed Bean, is it possible ?

Example, I have the following condition, from a p:dataTable:

```
<p:column >
                             <h:commandLink action="#{tableBean.list(ind)}" >  
                                <i class="cus-find"></i> 
                            </h:commandLink>  
                        </p:column>
```

I want to call a Managed Bean and open a popup through it, is it possible ?

```
public String list(InfoListVO ind){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("InfoListVO ", ind);

//here I want to return my page in a popud directly from a Managed Bean
    return "myPage";
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hey, why do you want it in your managed bean ?

Comment: Because I want to process the parameters before render my table again in other window, thus, the line of my table are the parameters for resize another table in another window

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found this RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('nomeDoDialog').show();");

Comment: But your answer is correct to, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the managed Bean but I think it's gonna do the trick for your purpose.

```
   <p:commandLink action="#{tableBean.list(ind)}" oncomplete="showMyPage()">  
        <i class="cus-find"></i> 
   </p:commandLink>
```

You can do the business you want in the function called by action, the javascript is executed after so you can send it args.